# AngularJS - weird error when making calculation on object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this calculation

```
if (typeof $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'] !== 'undefined') {
    $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'] = $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'];
}
else {
    $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'] = 0;
}
```

This looks very normal and obviously has no error.

However, if I attempt to do a simple calculation on that property, i.e.

```
if (typeof $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'] !== 'undefined') {
    // add 10
    $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'] = $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'] + 10;
}
else {
    $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'] = 0;
}
```

Then AngularJS throws a bunch of errors that I have no idea that they mean (see screenshot)

Also, despite the error, it would still do the calculation but the value is not correct (would return something like a few thousand)

What should potentially be the issue here? I think it could be something to do with the digest cycle.

[image]

Comment: Which value contains `$scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total']`before doing any operation with it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type of the total property using $log API and also keep checking for the other properties as like below:

```
if ($scope.memoryTable &&
    $scope.memoryTable[name] &&
    $scope.memoryTable[name][category] &&
    $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'] && 
    typeof $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'] !== 'undefined') {

    // check the type of total
    $log.log("type of the total" + typeof $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total']);
    // add 10
    $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'] += 10;
}
else {
    $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'] = 0;
}
// Check the value
$log.log("value of the total" + $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks $scope.memoryTable or ...['total'] is in $watch somewhere. So in between $digest cycle you again trying to modify it.

var total = $scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'];

if (typeof total !== 'undefined')    {

```
total += 10;
```

}    else    {

```
total = 0;
```

}

$scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total'] =  total;

Comment: Yeah sounds like it but still has error. Assigning new value to `$scope.memoryTable[name][category]['total']` would also touch it, which would distort the $digest cycle?

Comment: First check what is value & type of total before if condition.